# Where is a good location to HIDE Shortcuts for User Global Shortcut Key actions Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts

Total re-write, my problems changed quite a bit.

I have 9 shortcuts using Nircmd , they will control the volume if it works correct.
I put My KEY shortcuts into the properties for the shortcuts CTRL-KP7  , CTRL-KP1 etc.

The 2 locations that worked (so far) were the desktop , even foldered, the start menu, even way deep in the menu and foldered.  both still have the problem of the Taskbar rising.

Problem Now is, the system pops up the Auto Hide Windows 7 taskbar when I hit the Key shorcuts.
This problem does not seem to be related to nircmd, or the volume adjustment. it seems to be related to the KeyShorts running via the system itself. a 3rd party program (which had its own problems) did not have the taskbar problem, when running the same shortcuts.

The system is using a "classic" theme , not the Areo render theme.

If you know of the limitations and requirements for the windows 7 Users ShortKeys to operate globally, where would be a good place to stick them so they do not get in the way? I am hoping that someone has done this before, saving me time hunting and testing.

---

**Solved** the other problem of Hotkey leftovers , that I got into while trying this.

Now I went and did the same thing others have , of getting a global key assignment stuck. 
Here is what I know so far about getting a Key shortcut unstuck.  Find them, remove them, Re-Boot the system.
It seems that the system picks up the shortcut info from the .Lnk and .url files themselves, there is no registry storage.

This picture, of the .LNK shortcut shows the location of an assigned hotkey, the location was consistant with other files.    A program that seeks out this data chunk in the file could find out where Keyshorts are in Shortcuts

[image]

---

Programs that get close to being helpfull, when it comes to locating global Key Shortcuts.

2 free programs I found One scans the keys for the ones that are used. 
"Activehotkeys" Instead of finding the keys, or anything knowing what program or where they are, it Tests for them. I would guess that it does a brute force :-) type of testing. Racing through them to see what is used. The columns can be sorted bringing the keys with Yes Status to the top of the sort. That covers only the existance of the key being used , which is of little whole value to removing one.

"Windows HotKey Explorer" Will show the windows ones , and the ones that are in place by shortcuts for the system, but not the location of the shortcut/file they are in. In the 64bit the program has to be put into windows 7 compatability mode or it locks up.

---

Edit:  Now the shorts that are in a Folder on the desktop do not Stay past a boot, I can re-set them. The desktop is set to not show icons at all, and I could have turned something off that was needed.
   Add to that
 The nircmd really doesnt handle the "focused" well, because nircmd itself pulls focus.  I have done a few tricks to get focused to work 70-80% but this is becomming a waste. A good resident program that could work with the new featured of the PER-APP volume control shouldnt have these problems.
Notes: by focused, I mean the control needs to apply to the top open program, not be designated, flipping focus to next arbitraty window doesnt help when it is not consistantly pulling focus itself.
What a mess, lets just add another layer of things that dont work.

Comment: You can hide all your hotkeys in a single AutoHotkey script/executable. ;)

Comment: @iglvzx  well i got 2 lost in the system now. I found that the .LNK holds them around 33 64 in the file (whatever that means). there doesnt seem to be any other flag for them. I just need a seeker program.  Autohotkey wouldnt it have to be running? or can it effect the systems own globals ?  I already have to use nircmd which is Way slower than a program would be to talk to this stuff.  Add to that I have some other 3rd party hook for the mouse that works pretty buggy.

Comment: An AutoHotkey script does need to be running in the background, but it can override any keyboard shortcuts or input.